# Is it normal to get different graphs for same data after umap

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, scikit-learn

I am not sure how can I describe all the steps that I am taking but basically my question is simple:
I use same code, same data from text file, gather some statistics about that data and then use umap for 2D reduction.

**Is it normal to have different graphs when I plot the result?**

I use scikit-learn, umap-learn, ggplot2.

The continuation of the problem is when I use hdbscan. Because every time I run the code, the plot is different, then cluster size and clusters become different and so on. I am wondering if this is something expected or not, basically.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I did the UMAP with `random.seed(32)` but when I pass it to HDBSCAN for clustering it reproduces different results everytime. Did you solve the problem? If yes can you update?
Also this looks like an open issue for HDBSCAN: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/326
So I am not entirely sure if the problem lies at UMAP or HDBSCAN. PS. I could not comment this, that is the reason why I posted this as an answer. Yes I did read the tips on answers, I understand that this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. Dimensions reduction algorithms like `tSNE` and `uMAP` are stochastic, so every time you run the clustering and values will be different. If you want to keep the same graph you need to set a common seed. You can achieve that in R by setting the seed (e.g. `set.seed(123)`) before calling `uMAP` (or set flag if the function allows that). `np.random.seed(123)` should work in python scikit.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Fra. I will try to set seed before calling umap. Does 123 means anything special or how should I choose the seed?

Comment: It could be anything you want. There are loads of posts about it on this site, they probably explain it much better than I could ever do.

Comment: python's UMAP has a `random_state` flag